# How to add delete button at bottom instead of Cancel in SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, survey-list, button, edit-update-delete

I am trying to add delete button instead of cancel in a SharePoint Online Survey list. working on small customization of survey list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Classic experience then you can add the content editor webpart on the list forms and can use the JavaScript/jQuery to hide the default cancel button and add new delete button.

But if you are using modern experience then you can modify the list form in PowerApps.

Comment: Thanks Harminder for the reply, I am using classic page, do you have a command for adding delete button in JavaScript/JQuery? If you shared it would be really helpful.